# Program getting stuck in a function call after the garbage collector getting called

Tags: go, winapi, garbage-collection, freeze

I'm building a windows aplication in Go using pure win32 api functions. My application suddenly hangs or gets stuck out of nowhere randomly. No error message or panic from go debugger. And the worst part is the problem is not appearing all the time but occasionally. I tried to put some 'log.Println' here and there in my program to trace exactly where it's getting stuck at and it appeared it's getting stuck at random places at random function calls but mostly, it's getting stuck at win32 api function calls like 'DefWindowProc' or 'GetMessage'. Over time my project got bigger and the more it got bigger the more often the problem seems to appear. So I tried to minimize the codes, simplify and comment out codes as much possible to see if the problem still occurs and I don't know it isn't helping much cause the problem just occurring randomly and my mind is a mess now.

I can just post codes from my original program but I'm not sure if those would help or not. I can show them if required. Now I've discovered something else which may or may not be related to my original problem. I was thinking if the garbage collector causing it since it gets called randomly if I'm doing something that is not GC friendly. I really don't know but here is this simple code. I never called the GC manually in my original application codes but here I'm doing it for test purpose.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "runtime"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/AllenDang/w32"
)

func main() {

    w32.CreateWindowEx(
        0, syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("Button"), syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("Hello World!"),
        w32.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|w32.WS_VISIBLE,
        100, 100, 1200, 800, 0, 0, 0, nil)

    runtime.GC()

    var msg w32.MSG
    for {
        log.Println("Calling 'GetMessage'")
        if w32.GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) == 0 {
            break
        }
        log.Println("End Calling 'GetMessage'")
        w32.TranslateMessage(&msg)
        w32.DispatchMessage(&msg)
    }
    return
}
```

The program doesn't go past the 'GetMessage' it gets stuck there. But if I comment out the 'runtime.GC()' then it does work perfectly. I'm coming from C++ and new to Go. I don't know much about how Go language's garbage collector works and I don't seem find any garbage that's getting collected there in those codes. Please help me out I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is never (practically) a need to call runtime.GC.

Comment: @Volker I'm aware of that and that's why I mentioned in my question that I never called the runtime.GC manually in my codes but here I'm doing it to observe what happens when it gets called. And I'm not sure calling it why making the program get stuck at 'GetMessage'. I would appreciate if you can tell me or help me in any way. Thanks

Comment: Not familiar with win32, but `CreateWindowEx` call returns a value. Perhaps that call created some data which needs to persist for the lifetime of the object?

Comment: @JimB Well to be very honest I'm also not aware of what exactly CreateWindowEx does under the hood. Its a system function from User32.dll library of Windows API. The 'w32' go package uses the syscall function of golang to call CreateWindowEx

Comment: What I mean is just test if holding that value alive works. The `GetMessage` call also takes a `HWND` as a parameter, is it supposed to be passed there as well?

Comment: @JimB And the CreateWindowEx actually creates a GUI control (button, eEdit control, list box etc.) and returns the id of it as an integer

Comment: If it helps, the garbage collector should not effect the program correctness in any way. If the `w32` package is being used correctly and yet is effected by GC, that is a bug in the `w32` package.

Comment: @JimB I tried to hold the return value even tried to use the 'runtime.KeepAlive' but it didn't work. The GetMessage doesn't need the HWND parameter usually but still, just for the sake of testing, I just tried to pass the return value of CreateWindowEx to it. Didn't work either

Comment: @JimB Exactly my thought that the garbage collector should not effect my codes. And the w32 package is just a wrapper for the Win32Api and there are bunch of Win32Api wrappers out there on the Github. I tried them all. The result is same, unfortunately.

Comment: Another idea, it may only be a side effect of the GC process, not the garbage collection itself. Many systems require thread-local context, and calling the functions from different threads may not work. Try running all the code in a single dedicated goroutine that calls [`runtime.LockOSThread`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/#LockOSThread)

Comment: @JimB I wasn't aware of that. I will try it and lets see how it goes. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JimB calling `runtime.LockOSThread` solved my problem. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: This is very common for GUI code in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems @JimB is right, I need to call `runtime.LockOSThread` before calling the OS API functions. If I call `runtime.LockOSThread` before calling them the program doesn't hang anymore. Still a lot to learn for sure.